# How to turn a nested json array into $row to insert into database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Im trying to take the following nested array

```
echo $json['events']['data']['0']['place']['location']['street'];
echo $json['events']['data']['0']['description']; echo '<br><br>';
echo $json['events']['data']['0']['name']; echo '<br><br>';
echo $json['events']['data']['0']['end_time']; echo '<br><br>';
echo $json['events']['data']['0']['start_time']; echo '<br><br>';
echo $json['events']['data']['0']['place']['location']['city']; echo '<br><br>';
echo $json['events']['data']['0']['place']['location']['street']; echo '<br><br>';
```

and turn it into into a

```
echo "id:".$row["id"] . "|Type:".$row["TYPE"]. "|Name:".
$row["Name"]. "|Description:".$row["Description"] . 
"|Start_time:".$row["Start_time"] . "|End_time:".
$row["End_time"] . "|Date:".$row["street"] .
```

- which is supposed to show the data of street' so i can put it into my database, but how do i put the nested array into the $row statement?

I'm tyring to create a database but i have to declare the nested array in order to reference it.

Usually im able to write the code like this without nested arrays, but i'm not sure how to do it when it's nested.

```
echo "id:".$row["id"] . "|Type:".$row["TYPE"]. "|Name:".
        $row["Name"]. "|Description:".$row["Description"] . "|Start_time:".$row["Start_time"] . "|End_time:".
        $row["End_time"] . "|Date:".$row["street"] . ";";
```

```
JSON sample 

 {
   "events": {
      "data": [
         {
            "description": "Et af landets st\u00f8rste poptalenter Ea Kaya spiller sin f\u00f8rste headliner koncert i K\u00f8benhavn p\u00e5 Hotel Cecil den 17. april 2020.\n\nEa Kaya stormede frem med debutsinglen \u201cRemedy\u201d i 2017 og blev hurtigt sp\u00e5et til at v\u00e6re Danmarks nye internationale guldkorn. Sangerinden har i dag millioner af lyttere, og i januar udgav hun sin debut-EP \u201cFragile But Strong As Hell\u201d. EP\u2019en indeholder bl.a. \u201c4 AM\u201d, der gik hen og l\u00e5 i Top 5 p\u00e5 radio.\n\nEa Kayas umiddelbarhed er et gennemg\u00e5ende tr\u00e6k i hendes musik. Ea Kaya skriver tekster, der er s\u00e5 direkte og n\u00e6rv\u00e6rende, at man kommer helt t\u00e6t p\u00e5, samtidig med at lytteren selv kan spejle sig i hendes musik. \n\nDe klare holdninger g\u00e5r igen i Ea Kayas presse. Sidstn\u00e6vnte kan eksempelvis l\u00e6ses i hendes interview med Innovative Artist Academy: \u201cMan m\u00e5 have den indstilling, at musikken er s\u00e5 god, at den skal ud lige meget hvad\u201d, eller i sangerindens f\u00f8rste feature med Soundvenue: \u201cMan bliver hurtigt kaldt bossy, hvis man har en mening.\u201d\n\nDe sidste par har m\u00e5neder har Ea Kaya v\u00e6ret i studiet, hvor hun sammen med en nyfunden kerne af dygtige mennesker arbejder intenst p\u00e5 hendes lyd. Artisten holder sine kort t\u00e6t ind til kroppen, men hun gl\u00e6der sig til at l\u00f8fte sl\u00f8ret for nyt materiale til koncerten p\u00e5 Hotel Cecil.\n\n\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\nEa Kaya p\u00e5 spillestedet Hotel Cecil\nBilletpris: 140kr + gebyr\nBilletsalg: www.ticketmaster.dk/event/CEC2111\nBaren \u00e5bner kl. 18 \nD\u00f8re til koncertsalen \u00e5bner kl. 19 / koncertstart kl. 20\nwww.hotelcecil.dk/arrangementer/ea-kaya/\n\nTilmeld dig Hotel Cecils nyhedsbrev: ",
            "end_time": "2020-04-17T23:00:00+0200",
            "name": "Ea Kaya \u0040Hotel Cecil, K\u00f8benhavn",
            "place": {
               "name": "Hotel Cecil",
               "location": {
                  "city": "Copenhagen",
                  "country": "Denmark",
                  "latitude": 55.67935,
                  "located_in": "601098586681278",
                  "longitude": 12.57771,
                  "street": "Niels Hemmingsens Gade 10",
                  "zip": "1153"
               },
               "id": "601098586681278"
            },
            "start_time": "2020-04-17T20:00:00+0200",
            "id": "308355233187445",
            "rsvp_status": "attending"
         },
```

Comment: You should provide more information, what is `$row['street'];`

Comment: Please explain your problem by providing sample data of `$json` as well add details about what is `$row['street']`. Until your question will be clear, no one can help you..

Comment: What is the problem to get data from nested array ?

Comment: do `$data = json_decode($json,true);$street = []; foreach($data['data'] as $values){$street[] = $values['street'];} print_r($street);`. you will get all streets in a single-dimensional array

Comment: thx dude, godspeed